# How to get rid of "Duplicate key" in python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, pylint

```
URL = {URL here}
page = requests.get(URL, headers={header here})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

container = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "data1", "class": "data2"})"
```

***Warning: Duplicate key 'class' in dictionary*** pylint(duplicate-key)

I wonder if it is possible to smash together "data1" and "data2" as one attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select element that has class `data1` *AND* `data2`, you can use CSS selector:

```
data = '''
<div>
  <div class="data1">data1</div>
  <div class="data1 data2">data1 AND data2</div>
</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('div.data1.data2').text) # or select() to select multiple elements
```

Prints:

```
data1 AND data2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use soup sieve, which come together with BeatifulSoup anyway

```
soup.select('div:is(.data1, .data2)')
```

check it out for more info: [soup sieve](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/)